# How can I check isViewLoaded using an XCAssert in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm writing XCUITests and I'd like to check if my ViewController has loaded. I'm thinking thinking to access the isViewLoaded Bool property.
How would that look as an assertion?

```
func XCTAssert(isViewLoaded == true, "MyViewController view loaded successfully")
```

The above code gives me an error. How would it look?

Comment: You cannot access your view controller objects in UI tests with XCTest. Do you mean unit tests?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `isViewLoaded` on an actual instance of a view controller. And the message you provide should indicate that the assertion failed, not succeeded.

```
let vc = ... // some view controller

XCTAssert(vc.isViewLoaded, "MyViewController view failed to load")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is what you want to happen - your expectation. The second parameter is the message that is used when an assertion FAILS. So you have to do it like this:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
XCTAssertTrue(viewController.isViewLoaded, "viewcontroller's view failed loading")
```